# How to get p-value for each row of two columns in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I would like to ask for any suggestion how to calculate p-value for each row in my pandas DataFrame. My dataframe looks like this - there are columns with means of Data1 and Data2, and then also columns with standard error of the means. Each row represent one atom. Thus I need calculate p-value for each row (= it means, e.g., compare mean of atom 1 from Data1 with mean of atom 1 from Data2).

```
    SEM-DATA1   MEAN-DATA1  SEM-DATA2   MEAN-DATA2  
0   0.001216    0.145842    0.000959    0.143103    
1   0.002687    0.255069    0.001368    0.250505    
2   0.005267    0.321345    0.003722    0.305767    
3   0.027265    0.906731    0.033637    0.731638    
4   0.029974    0.773725    0.150025    0.960804
```

I found here on Stack that many people recommend using scipy. But I dont know how to apply it in the way I need it.
Is it possible?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two samples `df['MEAN...1']` and `df['MEAN...2']`, so, you should do this:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.ttest_ind(df['MEAN-DATA1'],df['MEAN-DATA2'])
```

which return:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.01001479441863673, pvalue=0.9922547232600507)
```

or if you only want to p-value

```
a = stats.ttest_ind(df['MEAN-DATA1'],df['MEAN-DATA2'])
a[1]
```

which gives

```
0.9922547232600507
```

**EDIT**

A clarification is in order here. A t-test (or the aquisition of a "p-value" is aimed at finding out is two distributions are coming from the same population (or sample). Testing for two single values will give `NaN`.

Comment: This approach just takes whole columns, doesnt it? So, I should use axis=1 to calculate it for each row of the two columns?

Comment: p-values are for samples, not for 2 numbers. What do you expect the p-value of two numbers to be?